# How do I use Android Market and SlideMe at the same time?

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

**Background:**
I sell an [app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.punjabikosh) in the Android Marketplace, and am looking at moving from copy protection to Android Market Licensing.  At the same time, I want to make the app available in SlideMe using their [Slidelock](http://slideme.org/en/slidelock) licensing.

**Questions:**
What is the easiest way to implement two different license schemes at the same time?

Comment: You could just not bother with SlideMe. I sell there and get about 1/1000th of the action that I get on the Android Market. But that's just me maybe.

Comment: The selling through SlideMe is probably for adding paypal support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a check on both protection mechanisms and allow the app to run if at least one of them passes.

Comment: +1 You know Will, sometimes you just can't see the forest for all the trees!